# Saving float with more than 2 decimal digits

Tags: arduino

i'm using GPS NEO 6m with esp8266(NODEMCU) and uploading data to firebase
Using 
" Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);"  shows "Latitude= 34.200271"
But How to save **Latitude as local variable with 6 decimal degits ?**
using " float  latitude=(gps.location.lat()); only saves 34.20 "

and " float  latitude=(gps.location.lat(),6); only saves 6"
Thanks

Comment: how did you determine that assigning a float to float variable looses decimal places? it is an exact copy. the function `print(float val, int digits)` formats the output to required number of decimal places. (btw: operator `,` returns the last value in list)

Comment: A floating point number is a representation of a value.  It doesn't have a set number of decimals.  Actually you could say it has infinite number of decimal places.  When you call print on a floating point number it only prints two decimal places unless you tell it to print more.

Comment: I'm using  Serial.println(latitude);

Answer (score 0):

Storing the latitude in a flot should work without any problems.  BUT this line of code is wrong:

```
float latitude=(gps.location.lat(),6);
```

What you are doing is assigning the result of this operation: `(gps.location.lat(), 6)` to a float. The parenthesis operator is sure a strange one.  It will execute all operations separated with commas within the parenthesis in the order given but return the result of the LAST operation.  In this case, it's `6`.

Changing your line of code to:

```
float latitude = gps.location.lat();
```

Shoudl fix your problem.

Comment: actually I'm using Firebase, and uploading my GPS co-ordinates to firebase.
But now I just noticed that using 
"Firebase.setFloat ("Latitude", 123.658975 ); " also  upload to two decimal values only...
so problem lies in uploading the float to database, there might be any library for arduino/ NODEMCU for uploading bigger numbers I guess

Comment: The bug you are experiencing is a C++ language syntax issue.  You are instructing the compiler to execute `gps.location.lat()`and then store the value 6 in the variable laititude, And that what it does.   It's totally unrelated to the library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies, I manged uploading a Float of decimal point with 7 digit to Firebase  by using:

```
  char latitude[10]; 
  sprintf(latitude, "%.7f", gps.location.lat());
  Firebase.setString ("Latitude",latitude);

  delay(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

> using " float latitude=(gps.location.lat()); only saves 34.20 "

I think it saves all available decimal point to `latitude`

While printing/outputting use

```
Serial.println(latitude,6);
```